# Encountered the symbol "@" when

Tags: oracle, sequence

I am trying to update the value of `'company_code'` in the `'companies'` table to be numbered and in some sort of sequence.

I am trying to use this:

```
DECLARE 
@cmpcode INT
SET @cmpcode = 0 
UPDATE companies
SET @cmpcode = company_code = @cmpcode + 1
```

and it is giving me this error:

```
Error starting at line : 16 in command -
DECLARE 
@cmpcode INT
SET @cmpcode = 0 
UPDATE companies
SET @cmpcode = company_code = @cmpcode + 1 
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I apologize for asking about something I am sure is a stupid syntax oversight.

Thank you.

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find that syntax?

Comment: That's SQL Server/Sybase, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help?

```
DECLARE cmpcode INT;
BEGIN 
  cmpcode := 0; 
  UPDATE companies 
  SET company_code = cmpcode + 1
  WHERE <your where expression>;
END  
;
```

Comment: I think that would work, but I get a "unique constraint" error.

I am trying to create a loop to give them all a unique company_code

Comment: Your company code is a unique constraint you violated because you already have the value you're trying to update the column to.
  I don't know how well this would post, but try smth along the lines of: 
    select max(company_code)+1 into cmpcode from companies; 
before the update. Or use Oracle sequences.